# how to set up rotating images?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been looking around for a way to rotate my background image, Probably every 7 or 8 seconds. The problem is that it seems to me unclear how I would go about using the javascript of php code. Would I put it under the  tag or does it go in the body? Or do I upload it to my server? Sorry if this seems like a basic question, I am just a begginer.

Also what would be the best code to use? In your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload all your images in a folder on server each image with a number as file number

```
/Images/BG/...
```

Then use the following function to change the background of body

```
var currentImageIndex = 0;
var maxImageIndex = 10;
setTimeout(function()
{
    currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex  + 1;
    if(currentImageIndex > maxImageIndex) currentImageIndex = 0;

    $(body).css("background-image", "/Images/BG/" + currentImageIndex + ".JPG");
}, 7000);
```

remember to use 0's image as the background image by default (in CSS)